# Easiest way to split an unordered list into two columns

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to show elements of an unordered list in a two-column submenu using CSS? I want to achieve something like [this](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro-flyout-list.html), but without having several `<div>`s in the submenu. I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S9t7Y/19/), but I have two issues:

1. The submenu items do not align if they are of different widths (obvious) and I would like to keep that as it is because I do not know the length of each item
2. I cannot keep the top menu selected when hovering over it

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the widths to be fixed, but you do want them to be uniform in each column?

Comment: Actually you are right ... I should make their widths fixed.

Comment: Actually James Montagne responded to issues #1 and SKS on issue #2 ... how can I accept both answers?

Comment: I will thank you both however for the effort to answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the sumenu items do not align if they are of different width (obvious)
>   and I would like to keep that as it is because I do not know the
>   length of each item

You can use `min-width` for sub-menu li and so it would align or expand as per the contents.

```
#menu_main ul li ul li{
    display:block; 
    margin: 0; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

> I cannot keep selected the top menu (like when it is hovered)

Define a class `.active` as below in your css

```
a.active {color:#666 !important; background:white !important; border:2px solid #d5d5d5 !important; }
```

And Try below script,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mainop").hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("ul").slideDown("fast");
        $this.children('a:first-child').addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("ul").slideUp("fast");
        $this.children('a:first-child').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9t7Y/31/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to fixed widths then something like the following would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/S9t7Y/27/

```
#menu_main ul li ul {display:none; position: absolute; top:auto; left:auto;width: 400px;}
#menu_main ul li ul li{float: left; display:block; width: 197px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid red;}
```

Comment: Ultimately I agreed on fixed widths :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this jquery plugin [columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: That is a good one. I tried like this http://jsfiddle.net/S9t7Y/30/ but now the submenu does not show up anymore. Am I targeting the wrong way?